# ZendFramework DateTimeFormatterStrategy Format

Tags: php, datetime, zend-framework, zend-db

i got this String from the Database trough tableGateway

```
19-JAN-17 09.10.33.000000 PM
```

I'm trying to hydrate it using DateTimeFormatterStrategy.

so far i got this on my Hydrator Class:

```
$this->addStrategy('BEGINN', new DateTimeFormatterStrategy('d-M-y h.i.s.u A'));
```

But it's not right.

I which format could it be?

Thanks in advance.

Greets,

Ivan

Answer (score 0):

ok, sorry. My bad...
The problem are on the other part. I misstype the on the first parameter in the  addStrategy() Method.

Test with:

```
$format = 'd-M-y h.i.s.u A';
$time = '19-JAN-17 09.10.33.000000 PM';
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $time);
```

and $dt are instantiated in right DateTime object.